# How to find the common elements and total count of elements that are in DataFrame in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have below single DataFrame with columns as order_id , Order_date.

| Order_id | Order_date |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-11-16 |
| 2 | 2022-11-16 |
| 3 | 2022-11-16 |
| 4 | 2022-11-16 |
| 5 | 2022-11-17 |
| 6 | 2022-11-17 |
| 2 | 2022-11-17 |
| 1 | 2022-11-17 |
| 2 | 2022-11-18 |
| 7 | 2022-11-18 |

Here order_id 2 and 1 are in both 2022-11-16 and 2022-11-17. Similary in 2022-11-17 & 2022-11-18 order_id 2 is repeating. So i want to compare the dates and see how many order_id are comming from the previous date.

1. count the order_id which are comming from the previous day.

Could someone please help.

Expected Output:

```
2 - As count of 2 order_id is comming from 16 Nov to 17 Nov
1 - As count of 1 order_id is comming from 17 Nov to 18 Nov
```

Not sure how to acheive this. Did some research on it but did not find anything.

Comment: Can you format your dataframe and let us know your expected output

Comment: Updated the expected output

Answer (score 0):

You can sort the dates, compute the successive differences per group to filter the deltas equal to 1 day, and count them:

```
df['Order_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Order_date'])

(df.sort_values(by=['Order_id', 'Order_date'])
   .groupby('Order_id')['Order_date']
   .apply(lambda s: s.diff().eq('1d').sum())
   .loc[lambda s: s.gt(0)]
)
```

Output:

```
Order_id
1    1
2    2
Name: Order_date, dtype: int64
```